# Failed to use hosts `*-pim.webapi.com` and `pim.webapi.com` in istio VirtualService

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want to config the route strategy for `*-pim.webapi.com` and `pim.webapi.com`. When apply the yaml to k8s, it says the two hosts are duplicated. But I don't think they are duplicated because `*-pim.webapi.com` can not match `pim.webapi.com`. Is this a bug of istio or my mistake?

The VirtualService yaml is:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: public-ingress
  namespace: netops
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*-pim.webapi.com" 
  - "pim.webapi.com" 
  gateways:
  - public-ingress
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: pim.default.svc.cluster.local
```

The error message is

```
admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: duplicate hosts in virtual service: *-pim.webapi.com & pim.webapi.com
```

The source code for this error message is here https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pilot/pkg/model/validation.go#L1602. But there is no help to understand and solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Istio. The code you referenced calls [this function](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/9b27fa46b934a335c58b3ca7a944af35e8dd5133/pilot/pkg/model/service.go#L540) to decide if the hosts match, and it's clearly doing the wrong thing in your case.

I would try using one host `*pim.webapi.com`, and see if that works. I'm not sure it will because I thought that wildcards could only be used for the full value of the left most component of a domain name, i.e., `*.webapi.com`, but not `*pim.webapi.com`.

Comment: Wildcards could only be used for the full value of the left most component.

From Envoy's documentation: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/listener/listener.proto#envoy-api-msg-listener-filterchainmatch :

Note that partial wildcards are not supported, and values like *w.example.com are invalid.